# How to Create an Image from HTML Content with Specific Height Using Puppeteer Sharp

Tags: puppeteer, chromium, image-conversion, blink, html-to-image

We are attempting to convert HTML to an image using Puppeteer Sharp. However, we are encountering issues with extra white space being generated. For instance, when converting only a single-page content wrapped in a

tag, the conversion results in additional empty space.

Here is the code snippet we're currently using:

```cs
var options = new LaunchOptions { Headless = true, UserDataDir = "D:\\New folder" };

Console.WriteLine("Downloading chromium");

using var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync();

Console.WriteLine("Navigating to Google");
await using var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options);
await using var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

// Uncomment the following line to navigate to a specific URL
// await page.GoToAsync("https://www.google.com");

await page.SetContentAsync("\"<p>Hello</p>\"");

Console.WriteLine("Generating Image");
await page.ScreenshotAsync("image.png");

Console.WriteLine("Export completed");
```

The goal is to capture only the text area as shown in the provided image: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIgfv.png). We appreciate any guidance on ensuring that the generated image contains only the text without unnecessary white space.